# Combining JSON values based on key

Tags: python, json

I'm working on Python 2.6.6 and I'm struggling with one issue.

I have a large JSON file with the following structure:

```
{"id":"12345","ua":[{"n":"GROUP_A","v":["true"]}]}
{"id":"12345","ua":[{"n":"GROUP_B","v":["true"]}]}
{"id":"54321","ua":[{"n":"GROUP_C","v":["true"]}]}
{"id":"54321","ua":[{"n":"GROUP_D","v":["true"]}]}
{"id":"54321","ua":[{"n":"GROUP_E","v":["true"]}]}
{"id":"98765","ua":[{"n":"GROUP_F","v":["true"]}]}
```

And I need to merge the id's so they'll contain all the GROUPS as so:

```
{"id":"12345","ua":[{"n":"GROUP_A","v":["true"]},{"n":"GROUP_B","v":["true"]}]}
{"id":"54321","ua":[{"n":"GROUP_C","v":["true"]},{"n":"GROUP_D","v":["true"]},{"n":"GROUP_E","v":["true"]}]}
{"id":"98765","ua":[{"n":"GROUP_F","v":["true"]}]}
```

I tried using the 'json' library, but I couldn't append the values correctly. Also I tried to convert it all to a dictionary and append the values (GROUPS) to the key (id) as lists, but I got stuck on printing it all as I need to the output file.

I can do it using bash but it takes too long to parse all the information and rearrange it in the needed format.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: did you manage to get it working as a dictionary but you just couldnt save it with the right format?

Comment: I don't think that's valid JSON, at least according to http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: That's not a JSON structure; it's six separate JSON structures. Are they actually inside an array that you didn't show us? Or do you have a list of them or something?

Comment: Meanwhile, forget trying to "append to JSON structures". Import the JSON to native Python objects, process them as Python objects, then write them back out to JSON at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's get the JSON stuff out of the way.

Your file is not a JSON structure, it's a bunch of separate JSON objects. From your sample, it looks like it's one object per line. So, let's read this in to a list:

```
with open('spam.json') as f:
    things = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
```

Then we'll process this, and write it out:

```
with open('eggs.json', 'w') as f:
    for thing in new_things:
        f.write(json.dumps(thing) + '\n')
```

---

Now, you don't have a JSON structure that you want to append things to; you have a list of dicts, and you want to create a new list of dicts, merging together the ones with the same key.

Here's one way to do it:

```
new_things = {}
for thing in things:
    thing_id = thing['id']
    try:
        old_thing = new_things[thing_id]
    except KeyError:
        new_things[thing_id] = thing
    else:
        old_thing['ua'].extend(thing['ua'])
new_things = new_things.values()
```

There are a few different ways you could simplify this; I just wrote it this way because it uses no tricks that should be beyond a novice. For example, you could do by it sorting and grouping:

```
def merge(things):
    return {'id': things[0]['id'],
            'ua': list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(t['ua'] for t in things))}
sorted_things = sorted(things, key=operator.itemgetter('id'))
grouped_things = itertools.groupby(sorted_things, key=operator.itemgetter('id'))
new_things = [merge(list(group)) for key, group in grouped_things]
```

---

I didn't realize from you original question that you had tens of millions of rows. All of the above steps require loading the entire original data set into memory, processing with some temporary storage, then writing it back out. But if your data set is too large, you need to find a way to process one row at a time, and keep as little in memory simultaneously as possibly.

---

First, to process one row at a time, you just need to change the initial list comprehension to a generator expression, and move the rest of the code inside the `with` statement, like this:

```
with open('spam.json') as f:
    things = (json.loads(line) for line in f)
    for thing in things:
        # blah blah
```

… at which point it might be just as easy to rewrite it like this:

```
with open('spam.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        thing = json.loads(line)
        # blah blah
```

---

Next, sorting obviously builds the whole sorted list in memory, so that's not acceptable here. But if you don't sort and group, the entire `new_things` result object has to be alive at the same time (because the very last input row could have to be merged into the very first output row).

---

Your sample data seems to already have the rows sorted by `id`. If you can count on that in real life—or just count on the rows always being grouped by `id`—just skip the sorting step, which isn't doing anything but wasting time and memory, and use a grouping solution.

---

On the other hand, if you can't count on the rows being grouped by `id`, there are only really two ways to reduce memory further: compress the data in some way, or back the storage to disk.

---

For the first, Foo Bar User's solution built a simpler and smaller data structure (a dict mapping each id to its list of uas, instead of a list of dicts, each with an id and a ua), which should take less memory, and which we could convert to the final format one row at a time. Like this:

```
with open('spam.json') as f:
    new_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for row in f:
        thing = json.loads(row)
        new_dict[thing["id"]].extend(thing["ua"])
with open('eggs.json', 'w') as f:
    for id, ua in new_dict.items(): # use iteritems in Python 2.x
        thing = {'id': id, 'ua': ua}
        f.write(json.dumps(thing) + '\n')
```

---

For the second, Python comes with a nice way to use a dbm database as if it were a dictionary. If your values are just strings, you can use the `anydbm`/`dbm` module (or one of the specific implementations). Since your values are lists, you'll need to use `shelve` instead.

Anyway, while this will reduce your memory usage, it could slow things down. On a machine with 4GB of RAM, the savings in pagefile swapping will probably blow away the extra cost of going through the database… but on a machine with 16GB of RAM, you may just be adding overhead for very little gain. You may want to experiment with smaller files first, to see how much slower your code is with `shelve` vs. `dict` when memory isn't an issue.

---

Alternatively, if things get way beyond the limits of your memory, you can always use a more powerful database that actually *can* sort things on disk. For example (untested):

```
db = sqlite3.connect('temp.sqlite')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE Things (tid, ua)')
for thing in things:
    for ua in thing['ua']:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO Things (tid, ua) VALUES (?, ?)',
                  thing['id'], ua)
c.commit()
c.execute('SELECT tid, ua FROM Things ORDER BY tid')
rows = iter(c.fetchone, None)
grouped_things = itertools.groupby(rows, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
new_things = (merge(list(group)) for key, group in grouped_things)
with open('eggs.json', 'w') as f:
    for thing in new_things:
        f.write(json.dumps(thing) + '\n')
```

Comment: good job i thought `defaultdict` would be better, but this seems to be the best approeach.

Comment: @FooBarUser: The problem with `defaultdict` is that you'd need to write a pretty complicated function to create the structure you want and/or a complicated expression to update it. But as I said in a comment to your answer, if you just build the structure `defaultdict` _can_ build easily, I think you can transform it into the right structure with a one-liner afterwards.

Comment: @FooBarUser: I've edited your answer to show what I mean. I think it's a better answer than my first version, and just as novice-friendly. (I still like my `groupby` solution, but I don't want to try explaining it…)

Comment: @abarnert - Thanks a lot! To your question in the question topic, it's not an array, it's just how the file structured, it contains ~10M records like this. I was able to run your code with one small adjustment, on the:
`with open('eggs.json', 'w') as f:
    for thing in new_things:
        f.write(json.dumps(thing) + '\n')
`
I changed the `new_things` to `things`.
I tried to run it over all the 10M records, but it fails with some encoding issues which I now try to isolate.

Comment: I was able to run it on the 10M records file, it took `real    73m17.105s` and I've seen that python took about 15g of memory while he ran it. I wonder whether something can be done in order to improve the resource consumption and the running time? Thanks!

Comment: @Eluha: Why did you change from `new_things` to `things`? What's wrong with what's in `new_things`?

Comment: @Eluha: Meanwhile, you can improve memory usage by making `things` a generator expression rather than a list comprehension, so you only have to process one row at a time instead of all 10M rows. Let me edit the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: @abarnert: Wow! No.. WOW!!! Great answer! I'll start experimenting first thing next week (I don't have access now to the large files) and would keep you posted with my findings. Thanks again, your effort and time very much appreciated and your guidance made a beginner Pythonist a lot less confused and very smiley! :)

Comment: @abarnert - oh, and for you question about: _Why did you change from `new_things` to `things`? What's wrong with what's in new_things?_ - that's because under the `try` in the `for` statement `new_things` weren't defined, so I thought you meant there the `things` row which, actually, worked :)

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong in my previous comment, i meant under the second `with` statement (eggs.json) the `new_things` var wasn't defined, and because you used `things` in the first `with` statement (spam.json) I thought you actually meant `things`, which when I changed it it worked.

Comment: @Eluha: The `new_things` is defined by the "process this" code that goes in between those parts, and the whole rest of the question is about how to create that `new_things`. If you do all that work, then just ignore the results and write back out the original `things`, that doesn't do any good. (Some of the versions actually mutate `things` along the way, so they _might_ work. But that's not the goal.)

Comment: @abarnert: I started experimenting with the `defaultdict` solution and it seems to run much quicker `real    35m35.651s`, but still it uses a lot of memory for creating the `new_dict`, but at this point it doesn't matter me a lot, because I have a dedicated server for this calculations. I would test the sqlite solution within the upcoming days. Thanks a lot for all your help!